# Jackson MessageSerializer freezes but application does not crash

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I'm building a Restful Web Application with Spring and Hibernate. For serialization I'm using the Jackson library (version 2.x).

The problem I'm facing is the following: I have a users, items and ratings, they look something like the following:

```
public class Item {
    ...
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Rating.class, mappedBy = "rating", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Set<Rating> rating = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}

public class Rating {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Item.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="item_id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Item item;
    ...
}


public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Rating.class, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<Rating> ratings  = new ArrayList<Rating>();
    ...
}
```

Now if i try to save a new rating for an item by a specific user is use a method that does something like this:

```
if(formerVoting != null) { //Previously fetched from the DB
    item.removeUserRating(formerVoting);
}
Rating newRating = new Rating(); //Create new Rating
newRating.setRating(rating);
newRating.setItem(item);
newRating.setUser(user);
user.addRating(newRating);
stop.addRating(newRating);
userDao.update(user);
stopDao.update(stop);
return stop;
```

This bit does also work, but when Jackson tries to serialize the `ResponseEntity` I return from my controller it just freezes.

I verified that the mehtod returns and tweaked the cascades but nothing helps. Does anyone know what I do wrong?

BR,
wastl

**EDIT:**

I finally figured out what the problem was:

I used a custom serializer for a field of item and it threw an exception. Apperently Jackson did not propergate this exception properly and the server just did not return anything.

Comment: First of all what was the payload size? Please note that Serialization and De-serialization requires lots of memory. You might not see the errors probably you kill the application before it throws a OutOfmemory error. Can you try setting a little more on -Xmx and try?

Comment: i have really small data sets for the first tests, and have serialized much larger and deeper ones (in the same application), so i highly doubt that it has to do with memory, but i'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You have a two-way relationship between `User` and `Rating`. Hibernate can usually deal with circular references gracefully, but Jackson takes a bit of work (actually, this is a potential problem any time you force an object graph into a tree structure). You'll have to decide how to serialize your objects; if `User` is the top-level object (the root of the JSON tree), then you need to tell Jackson to ignore the `user` field in `Rating`. Otherwise, it'll get stuck in infinite recursion.

The `@Cascade` annotation has nothing to do with Jackson, so forget that for now.

Comment: to avoid infinite loops i use the @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) which only serializes the id of the objects.

Comment: You're right, that should have taken care of the circular references. I take back what I said.